# Distinct records by field string

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

Using oracle sql,  I need to distinct records of a table by a string.

How it looks like(every row is a column of the table):

```
Data data ID1 data data
Data data ID2 data data
Data data ID1 data data
```

And I need to distinct by ID string.
The result I expect is something like this:
    Data data ID1 data data
    Data data ID2 data data
Is it possible?

Comment: Does `Data data ID1 data data` represent the contents of a single column in your table, or is this 5 different columns?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To get the most out of the site, please read the following so that you can ask better questions and improve your chances of someone being able to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide us more information about what result you're expecting. do you want a result with one ID column where you would like to have two rows containing ID1 and ID2 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want two columns only displaying distinct values of a given column use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColumnName FROM YourTable;
```

You can see a live example here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_distinct